# Can a foreigner enter Spain unvaccinated?

Tags: covid-19, travel, spain

Is it possible to enter Spain by plane unvaccinated? I see here: [https://travelsafe.spain.info/en/requirements-before-arriving-in-spain-from-third-countries/#:~:text=1.,vaccination%20course%20against%20COVID%2D19](https://travelsafe.spain.info/en/requirements-before-arriving-in-spain-from-third-countries/#:%7E:text=1.,vaccination%20course%20against%20COVID%2D19).

That supposedly one may enter if you have one of the following:

a) Vaccination certificate: confirming that you have received a valid vaccination course against COVID-19.

b) Diagnostic test certificate: to confirm that you have had a negative diagnostic test.

c) Recovery certificate: confirming that, after a positive diagnostic test result, you have recovered from a SARS-CoV-2 infection.

**Can someone confirm?**

Comment: This might be the wrong SE. https://travel.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Item b) says that a diagnostic certificate is a valid alternative. So if you have had a test (within 24 hours before entrance) you should be fine. Also, the rules only apply if you enter by plane or ship. You can get to Spain by car without any requirement at all.

Comment: @PMF indeed, if the title of the linked page is correct it doesn't even apply to all arrivals in Spain by air or ship; it only applies to arrivals from outside the Schengen area and the EU.  I flew to Spain from Switzerland about a month ago and I don't remember any documentation checks.

Comment: @phoog True, it's only for arriving from outside Schengen. It's kind of hard to arrive neither by air nor by boat in Spain from outside Schengen (even Gibraltar belongs to Schengen meanwhile, if I'm not mistaken).

Comment: @PMF Andorra is not part of the Schengen area and has border controls.  Apparently some people with single entry visas have gotten themselves in trouble there.  I have no idea what the COVID-19 controls are or were like there, however.

Comment: Just went to Tenerife. Nobody checked if I was vaccinated, so you _can_ enter without being vaccinated. Whether you can enter legally I don’t know.

Answer (score 1):

**Can a foreigner enter Spain unvaccinated?**

**Yes**

Although I have yet to find an official Spanish announcement, the UK Government's website for [Foreign Travel Advice, Spain](https://www.gov.uk/foreign-travel-advice/spain/entry-requirements#entry-rules-in-response-to-coronavirus-covid-19)
says that:

> From 21 October 2022, all COVID-19 travel restrictions for travellers to Spain have been lifted.

And a [euronews.com](https://www.google.co.uk/amp/s/www.euronews.com/travel/amp/2022/10/21/spain-travel-restrictions-covid-tests-vaxx-rules-and-masks-explained-in-full) article dated 21/10/2022 at 10:10 says:

> Spain has lifted all its remaining COVID restrictions. Until today, it was the only European country that still had restrictions in place for non-EU travellers.